# Sql 2 Tables Q?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have 2 tables 
JObs
id,description,name
TEST
id,jobid
I have created the query:

```
SELECT jobs.id,jobs.name,jobs.country,jobs.description,test.id,test.jobid
FROM jobs,test 
WHERE jobs.userid='10'
AND 
GROUP BY jobs.id
```

It echos me all jobs but test id is in all 1
If I make it `where jobs.id=test.jobid` the result is known.
How Can I print all jobs where `test.jobid` is equal to `job.id` and jobs that don't have a `test.jobid`

Comment: you're doing a cartesian join: you have NO restrictions on how your ttwo tables should be joined, so mysql is joining each record in `jobs` against EVERY record in `test`. that means you're getting `n x m` results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a left join command.

```
SELECT jobs.id AS jobs_id,jobs.name,jobs.country,jobs.description,test.id AS test_id,test.jobid AS job_id_from_test
    FROM jobs
    LEFT JOIN test ON test.jobid = jobs.id
    WHERE jobs.userid='10'
```

-Might help. The above code adds the left join command and takes out the unnecessary 'AND' and 'GROUP BY' statements. LEFT JOIN, unlike a normal JOIN, will return all applicable values for the jobs table, even if there isn't a corresponding row in the test table.

Answer (score 1):

what you had was a cross join.  This is not what you want.  You want a left join.

Like this

```
SELECT jobs.id,jobs.name,jobs.country,jobs.description,test.id,test.jobid
FROM jobs
left join test on jobs.id = test.jobid
WHERE jobs.userid='10'
GROUP BY jobs.id
```

Comment: You better put more in that GROUP BY statement...

Comment: @kbball -- this is mysql -- it lets you be lazy.

Comment: thanks only edit jobs.id=test.jobid